# Node.js. Filtering through a collection of referenced objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having issues filtering through an array of ObjectId's, which are a reference to another model. And to return an error if one or more with that ObjectId already exists within the array.

This is what the model looks like in the database

[image: Text]

And this is my code

````
// @route  PUT api/profile/favorites/:id
// @desc   Add recipe to favorites
// @access Private
router.put('/favorites/:id', auth, async (req, res) => {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);

    try {
        const profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id });

        const newFav = {
            _id: post._id,
            by: post.name,
            nameOfDish: post.nameOfDish
        };

        console.log(profile.favorites.valueOf());

        // Check if the post has already been added to favorites
        if (profile.favorites.filter((favs) => favs.valueOf().toString() === post._id).length > 0) {
            return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Post already been favorited' });
        }

        profile.favorites.unshift(newFav);

        await profile.save();

        res.json(newFav);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
}); ```
````

Comment: can you also add `console.log(JSON.stringify(profile.favorites))` to code and paste the output in your question?

Comment: I'm getting the same output as console.log(profile.favorites.valueOf()); Which is an array of strings for each 15 of the same Objects

Comment: then shoudln't this line `profile.favorites.filter` be `profile.favorites.valueOf().filter` ?

Comment: Is the output of `profile.favorites.valueOf()` is what is been displayed at the top.  If so you would want .->  `profile.favorites.valueOf().favorites`

Answer (score 0):

Your code should still work. Are you sure the value and type of `fav.valueOf().toString()` and `post._id` are the same?

---

On a different note, why not use `.find()` method? It'll make the code easier to read.

Replace

```
profile.favorites.filter((favs) => favs.valueOf().toString() === post._id).length > 0
```

with

```
profile.favorites.find(fav => fav.valueOf().toString() === post._id)
```